# Neovim LSP Not working after not using for a few months. (LSP Zero)

Tags: parsing, lua, neovim

I haven't used `NeoVim` in quite a while so excuse my poor explanation, but essentially my autocomplete A.K.A `LSP` No longer works.

I use `LSP Zero` and a custom completions config that has worked for me up until now, but no longer works.

Here is the section within my `plugins.lua` file which uses `packer.nvim`

```lua
-- LSP Configuration
    use({
        "VonHeikemen/lsp-zero.nvim",
        branch = "v1.x",
        requires = {
            -- LSP Support
            { "neovim/nvim-lspconfig" }, -- Required
            { "williamboman/mason.nvim" }, -- Optional
            { "williamboman/mason-lspconfig.nvim" }, -- Optional

            -- Autocompletion
            { "hrsh7th/nvim-cmp" }, -- Required
            { "hrsh7th/cmp-nvim-lsp" }, -- Required
            { "hrsh7th/cmp-buffer" }, -- Optional
            { "hrsh7th/cmp-path" }, -- Optional
            { "saadparwaiz1/cmp_luasnip" }, -- Optional
            { "hrsh7th/cmp-nvim-lua" }, -- Optional
            { "onsails/lspkind.nvim" },

            -- Snippets
            { "L3MON4D3/LuaSnip" }, -- Required
            { "rafamadriz/friendly-snippets" }, -- Optional
        },
    })
```

And my `completion.lua` file

```lua
local luasnip = require("luasnip")
local cmp = require("cmp")
local lspkind = require("lspkind")

cmp.setup({
    formatting = {
        format = lspkind.cmp_format({
            with_text = true, -- do not show text alongside icons
            maxwidth = 50, -- prevent the popup from showing more than provided characters (e.g 50 will not show more than 50 characters)

            -- The function below will be called before any actual modifications from lspkind
            -- so that you can provide more controls on popup customization. (See [#30](https://github.com/onsails/lspkind-nvim/pull/30))
            before = function(entry, vim_item)
                return vim_item
            end,
        }),
    },

    snippet = {
        expand = function(args)
            require("luasnip").lsp_expand(args.body)
        end,
    },
    mapping = {
        ["<C-p>"] = cmp.mapping.select_prev_item(),
        ["<C-n>"] = cmp.mapping.select_next_item(),
        ["<C-d>"] = cmp.mapping.scroll_docs(-4),
        ["<C-f>"] = cmp.mapping.scroll_docs(4),
        ["<C-Space>"] = cmp.mapping.complete(),
        ["<C-e>"] = cmp.mapping.close(),
        ["<CR>"] = cmp.mapping.confirm({
            behavior = cmp.ConfirmBehavior.Replace,
            select = true,
        }),
        ["<Tab>"] = function(fallback)
            if cmp.visible() then
                cmp.select_next_item()
            elseif luasnip.expand_or_jumpable() then
                luasnip.expand_or_jump()
            else
                fallback()
            end
        end,
        ["<S-Tab>"] = function(fallback)
            if cmp.visible() then
                cmp.select_prev_item()
            elseif luasnip.jumpable(-1) then
                luasnip.jump(-1)
            else
                fallback()
            end
        end,
    },
    sources = {
        { name = "nvim_lsp" },
        { name = "luasnip" },
        { name = "neorg" },
    },
})
```

I have tried re-installing my full config from `GitHub` and it doesn't seem as if I need to update anything but I'm not 100% on that. It has been a while since my last use of `NeoVim` so excuse my poor wording, any help is appreciated.

The `GitHub` that holds my config:

https://github.com/kawaleo/kawaleo.nvim/tree/config